# You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

For the past 3 years I have been doing the following to generate my SSL certificates for Google App Engine.

## Convert certificate to PEM format

```
openssl x509 -in domain.crt -out domain.pem -outform PEM
```

## Convert Private CSR Key to PEM format

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.pem
```

For some reason I am now getting this error when I click the upload button:

> You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate.

Can anyone shed some light one what I am doing wrong? I haven't changed this in years and now I am all the sudden getting issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the same happen at times.  Simply go to [Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home) and either re-verify the domain or make sure your current active account when you upload the certificate is an owner.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I appreciate the help