# You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate

Tags: ssl

Followed steps to "Securing Custom Domains with SSL" using our own organization's SSL certificate.  [Instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl)

When uploading our pem and private key I get the error message:

> You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate.

I followed a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470395/you-are-not-an-authorized-owner-of-the-domain-for-this-certificate-google-app-e) to verify via Webmaster Central.
I used the Meta Tag and uploading HTML methods to verify. 
However I still get the above error message.  Officially I maintain the Google app but the previous person who setup the domain mapping left the company.  Is there a way to make myself or my boss the "owner" of this custom domain mapping and how? We only have Bronze support so resolving this accounting issue is extremely difficult.

Thank you for any help or directions

EDIT: My boss handles the billing and is listed as "owner" under IAM, but even he can't upload anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be solved with the provider/hoster.

Comment: Under custom mapping, data column it lists "ghs.googlehosted.com".  Does this mean I have to go through Google Domains?

Comment: Here is an update.  I verified ownership through my company's DNS with the DNS CNAME record and still it doesn't want to upload.  We're using a company wildcard SSL certificate for the custom domain name which is a "[customdomainname].[companydomain].com".  Also I was given ownership and had my boss who is owner try it out.  Still no go.